# Save Error in Xml File With Elmah

Tags: elmah.mvc

I use elmah for find error . i want to save error in xml file. after i wrote Commands in cinfig file :

config file :

```
   <elmah>
    <security allowRemoteAccess="1"/>
    <errorlog type="Elmah.XmlFilerErrorLog, Elmah" logPath="~/App_Data" />
   </elmah>
```

How to access this xml file .is there this file in application ?

Answer (score 1):

you could try

> www.yourdomain.com/elmah.axd

Comment: @piet.t This is  actually not a link-only answer.